# UISwitch inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` as root controller. The `UINavigationController` is inside a `UIPopoverController`.
The `UITableViewController` contains a `UITableViewCell` (with a `UISwitch`) and a `UITableViewCell` (with `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`) that load another `UITableView` when tapped.

My problem is that when swipe on `UISwitch` and then tap the other cell, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called. If I tap again is called. If I tap the `UISwitch`, instead of swiping, there isn't any problem.

The problem is only on iOS4. On iOS5 works great!

My cellForRowAtIndexPath method is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

// Configure the cell...
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
switch (row) {
    case 0: {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.text = [controllers objectAtIndex:row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        UITextField *passwordTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 11, 400, 30)];
        passwordTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        passwordTextField.placeholder = @"Richiesta";
        passwordTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        passwordTextField.tag = 100;
        [passwordTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(passwordChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        passwordTextField.text = password;
        [cell addSubview:passwordTextField];
        [passwordTextField release];
        break;
    }

    case 1: {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.text = [controllers objectAtIndex:row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        UITextField *pinTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 11, 400, 30)];
        pinTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        pinTextField.placeholder = @"Richiesta";
        pinTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        pinTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        pinTextField.tag = 101;
        [pinTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(pinChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        pinTextField.text = aspin;
        [cell addSubview:pinTextField];
        [pinTextField release];
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        UITableViewController *controller = [controllers objectAtIndex:row];
        cell.textLabel.text = controller.title;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Busta Crittografica P7M (CAdES)";
        envelopeType = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Dichiaro di aver preso visione del documento, di sottoscriverne il contenuto e di essere consapevole della validità legale della firma apposta";
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        //add a switch
        UISwitch *switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(declarationChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        switchview.on = declaration;
        cell.accessoryView = switchview;
        [switchview release];
        break;
    }
}
return cell;
```

}

And my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
switch (row) {
    case 0: {
        [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:100] becomeFirstResponder];
        break;   
    }
    case 1: {
        [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:101] becomeFirstResponder];
        break;   
    }
    case 2: {
    ((CheckListController *)[self.controllers objectAtIndex:2]).contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.view.bounds.size;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.view.bounds.size;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.controllers objectAtIndex:2]
                                             animated:YES];
        break;   
    }
    default:
        break;
}
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

}

It's a very tricky problem and so I need your help!

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the code for *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* and *didSelectRowAtIndexPath:*? Are you using two different identifiers for creating the two cells (I see *CellIdentifier1*)?

Comment: What do you mean with swiping and tap the *UISwicth*? For me it makes no difference for the selection of your selectable cell.

Comment: If I press and move the finger on the UISwitch to change its state and then I tap another cell, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called. If I tap the UISwitch to change its state and then I tap another cell, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called. It seems that the problem is in the swipe. I'd like to point out that the UINavigationController with my UITableViewController is inside a UIPopoverController.

Comment: Ok. I solved my problem. I don't understand why but if I create my UITableViewController programmatically and not by Nib file, there isn't this problem. Flex_Addicted, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if could be a valid solution but you could try to clear the selection on for your table cell within your `declarationChanged:` selector.

```
- (void)declarationChanged:(id)sender
{
  // do your stuff here...
  //[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];

  UISwitch* s = (UISwicth*)sender;
  [s resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried you suggestion but with no luck. I'll try to create an example that reproduce the problem and I'll post it

Comment: Yesterday I have also tried with resignFirstResponder but with no use. Anyway I solved my problem. See my last comment at my question. Thank you very much.